# How do i show that this series converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $s_n$ denote the partial sums of the series $\sum a_n$.
>
> If $|s_n| < Mn^r$ for some $r<1$, then $\sum a_n/n$ converges

How do i prove this?

Comment: Have you tried summation by parts? Look up the wiki article for it.

Comment: @nayrb How do i apply summation by parts here?

Comment: @nayrb 1/n is monotonically decreasing sequence, hence i need to show that $|s_n|$ is bounded, but i the hypothesis doesn't not show that $|s_n|$ is bounded.

Comment: @Number 9 You "need" to show that *only* if you insist in proving  Dirichlet's Test applies here...but it could be it doesn't.

Comment: You shouldn't need to restrict yourself to the Dirichlet test. Summation by parts is just an identity that should allow you to rewrite the sum and use the comparison test. Anyways, DonAntonio's answer is a nicer one than using summation by parts.

Comment: @nayrb I think that only works if all (nonzero) $a_n$ have the same argument.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm too tired to work everything out but I don't see how that will be a problem. What one does is "convert" the sum to something like $\sum s_n (\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n})$ which converges absolutely. This doesn't mean the original sum converges absolutely, though.

Comment: @nayrb That's summation by parts, yes that works. I meant Don Antonio's answer works only under some additional conditions.

Answer (score 1):

the following is for the case we have a positive series: $\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;a_n\ge 0\;$

Suppose $\;m> 0\;$ :

$$S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}k\implies |S_{n+m}-S_n|=\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+m}\frac{a_k}k\right|\le\frac1{n+1}\left(s_{n+m}-s_n\right)\le$$

$$\le\frac{2M(n+m)^r}{n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;\;\;\implies$$

the sequence $\;\{S_n\}\;$ is Cauchy ...

Comment: I don't get it. How does $\sum a_k/k \leq |s_{n+m} - s_n|/n+1$ hold?

Comment: @Number9 put the least value of $k$ for all terms in series.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha Well, $a_n$ does not need to be positive here..

Comment: Of course not, @Number: nobody said $\;a_n\;$ is positive: $$\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+m}\frac{a_k}k\right|\le\frac1{n+1}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+m}a_k\right|=\frac1{n+1}\left|s_{n+m}-s_n\right|$$

Comment: @DonAntonio I feel myself very foolish now.. How the first inequality holds in your comment..? I was pointing out that $a_n$ need not to be positive since i don't get that inequality..

Comment: @Number9 then you need to modify a bit, i suppose ... putting max value for -ves and min value for +ves

Comment: @DonAntonio Take $m = 2$ and $a_{n+2} = -a_{n+1}$. The left hand side is nonzero, but the right is $0$.

Comment: @Number9, Oh I see now what you meant...and the foolish one is myself. Lemme see if I can mend this mess.

Comment: Yes indeed, @DanielFischer: that was clear to me after understanding what Number 9 meant. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I think my answer is unmendable as it is now, so I'm going to have to restrict it to the case $\;a_n\ge0\;\;\forall\;n\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio i think it's mendable

Comment: @SantoshLinkha, I'd appreciate your input in these comments.

Comment: In your comment, that inequality seems to be false, @SantoshLinkha: $$|as_+-bs_-|-|bs_+-as_-|\le |as_+-bs_-| ...$$

Comment: @DonAntonio woops!! sorry :( I'll have to think again

Comment: Thanks anyway, @SantoshLinkha :) We all may learn from everything, even from mistakes...I'm pretty sure the claim is true yet my way isn't in general...apparently.

Comment: @DonAntonio I proved it. Directly using summation by parts, it yields, $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k/k \leq \sum_{k=1}^n Mk^{r-1}$.